# Is there a way to type German and French characters from the stock keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, languages

I want to type French and German accents and stuff using some kind of add-on to the stock keyboard.  I don't want to switch between boards.  I see there are a lot of keyboards in the Play store but I need one that doesn't interfere with the stability of the stock one.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "long press" a key, which will give you alternative letters if alternative symbols are associated with it. Try it with the letter "E". To select the desired letter/symbol slide your finger to the side.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Anysoft Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard) for writing with accented, etc. characters. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/2atmt4/german_keyboard/.  this method works for me.

> Enable German keyboard by going to settings > language & input > then clicking the settings button next to Google keyboard >input languages > select German. To type ß, you'll need to hold down the s key, then it'll pop up, same for ü under u, Å under A, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Long press on keys gives alternate symbols. However for ß , you have to make sure the keyboard is in lower case as upper case would simply show SS instead of ß